# Are Cloud Datastore properties just "Columns"?

Tags: database, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform, terminology

Are the Cloud Datastore properties the equivalent of columns in SQL?

If so why are they called properties and not just columns. I've just started to learn GAE and I find it all confusing. "Entities", "Properties"... Why not rows and columns?

Comment: Thats because there are no rows and columns.  The datastore is not SQL or a RDBMS.  At the simplest level it's a key value store (the value has structure) (Yes it's not exactly that) and separate indexes.  Have a read of the background info on the datastore like this presentation from a past google i/o  https://sites.google.com/site/io/under-the-covers-of-the-google-app-engine-datastore

Comment: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities  could also be helpful.  Don't try to "map" it to SQL in your mind, you'll get confused even more when you try basic SQL stuff that won't work in the datastore.  there are a couple of IO videos explaining the background concept of the datastore, as Tim pointed out.  They could be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Entities and properties are internal terminology for [Megastore](https://research.google.com/pubs/pub36971.html) that were externalized when building and releasing Cloud Datastore.

Properties are very similar to Columns in SQL databases, although there are minor differences. Properties are defined at the entity level (equivalent to row) in Cloud Datastore, whereas Columns are defined table level (roughly maps to Kind in Cloud Datastore). This means that a property doesn't have to exist in every entity in a kind, unlike a column in a table.